# Nginx conditional access log not working

Tags: nginx, access-log, nginx-config

I am trying to make nginx's access log conditional using an `if` statement but its not working.

This is the relevant code from the configuration file.

```
map $uri $log_access {

    /.lb-check 0;

    default 1;
}

server {
    ...

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log combined if=$log_access;

    ...
}
```

I don't want certain requests to be logged, in this instance its a request made by the load balancer to the url `/.lb-check`

Unfortunately this configuration isn't working

I have also tried doing the following and that doesn't work either.

```
location = /.lb-check { access_log off; }
```

Does anyone know why these methods aren't working?

Comment: Your `access_log off` should absolutely work, so it more sounds like perhaps NGINX isn't reloading when you're applying that change. Ensure your configuration is valid with `nginx -t`. You may want to consider doing `location /.lb-check` instead fo `location = /.lb-check` in case you are also receiving requests for "/.lb-check/" which won't be covered

Answer (score 1):

This turned out to be a configuration issue with an internal build system but after solving that I ended up using the map method but with the `$request_uri` parameter

```
map $request_uri $log_access {

  /.lb-check 0;
  default 1;

}
```

`location = /.lb-check` didn't work as it overrode the handling of that request meaning nothing was defined to serve the request (should have gone to a php handler).